# C# Elegant way for retaining sign of original int/double variable after operations

Tags: c#

Is there a clever way to retain the sign of an integer/double variable after performing a bunch of operations on it? By elegant I'm probably looking more at bitwise operation or some sort of function to retain the sign.

Here's what I'd call the not-so-elegant way:

```
int myNum = -4;
bool isNegative = myNum < 0 ? true : false;
myNum += 8 / 2 % 4; //some operation
if ((isNegative && myNum > 0) || (!isNegative && myNum < 0))
    myNum *= -1;
```

---

Edit:
The operation in my particular scenario simply wants to change the magnitude of the number to match another numbers. So say myNum is -2, matchNum is 8, i want myNum to be -8.

Comment: Why are you trying to retain the original sign? Also, what sort of operations are allowed? Some more context might lead to some more clever solutions.

Comment: what's the sence of `myNum += 8 / 2 % 4` if you write it out it's `myNum = myNum + 8 / 2 % 4` <=> `myNum = myNum + 4 % 4` <=> `myNum = myNum` ... it's equal on both sides ... so it's a useless line of code

Comment: @Alex presumably it's just a nonsense operation intend to represent some unspecified operation which does not respect the sign of the original value.

Comment: The particular scenario I'm having is I have a 2D coordinate system. If abs(x) > abs(y) change the magnitude of y to match x and vice versa for abs(x) < abs(y). I said some operation to make it more generalized (out of curiosity if one does exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general way (as people have said, you'll need to compensate for `Math.Sign()` returning 0):

```
int myNum = -4;
int sign = Math.Sign(myNum);
myNum += 8 / 2 % 4; //some operation
myNum = Math.Abs(myNum) * sign;
```

A fun, fast, but unreadable way for integers which is immune to the `Math.Sign()` issue:

```
int origNum = -4;
int newNum = origNum + (8 / 2 % 4); //some operation

int signMask = (origNum ^ newNum) >> 31; // flip the sign of newNum if origNum
newNum = (newNum ^ signMask) - signMask; // and newNum have different signs.
```

Or perhaps for the floating-point types you can mask the sign bit, since they conform to IEEE 754. If the JIT is intelligent about this, it'll result in some very efficient SSE:

```
double myNum = -4.0;
long sign = GetSign(myNum);
myNum += 8.0 / 2.0 % 4.0; //some operation
myNum = SetSign(myNum, sign);

static long GetSign(double x)
{
    return BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(x) & signMask;
}

static double SetSign(double x, long sign)
{
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(x) & ~signMask | sign);
}

const long signMask = unchecked((long)(1UL << 63));
```

Comment: Be careful with this. `Math.Sign(0)` will return 0.

Comment: myNum = (sign > -1) ? Math.Abs(myNum) : -Math.Abs(myNum)

Comment: this answer's great, just need to do that check if sign comes back as 0. I'm fairly happy with this just waiting to see if anything else is out there before I accept it.

Comment: The other thing to note about the first form of this is that Math.Sign returns an integer even if the input is a floating point type, so there will have to be casting if the input is a floating point type.

Comment: Updated with a high-perf-yet-unreadable bitwise method which is immune to the `Math.Sign(0)` issue.

Answer (score 3):

*"The particular scenario I'm having is I have a 2D coordinate system. If abs(x) > abs(y) change the magnitude of y to match x and vice versa for abs(x) < abs(y)"*

Based on what you are actually trying to do an approach like this might be simpler:

```
int max = Math.Max(Math.Abs(x), Math.Abs(y));    // the larger of the two magnitudes
return (max * Math.Sign(x), max * Math.Sign(y));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be shortened to something like

```
int myNum = -4;
bool isNegative = myNum < 0;
myNum += 8 / 2 % 4; //some operation
myNum *= (isNegative == myNum < 0) ? 1 : -1;
```

If you want to try it bitwise, you could save the highest bit and use it as new sign, but in my opinion it would not be more elegant, but less readable.

Comment: Problem with bitwise is it'd only work for signed numbers which means double will fail. +1 for a nicer solution than mine anyway

Comment: fixed the last line, the boolean expression was not correct. You're right, I would not use bitwise operations on floats or doubles without a good reason.

Comment: I think your comparison in the last line is extremely cryptic. You should probably use `Math.Sign()` to be more explicit. `originalSign == Math.Sign(myNum) ? 1 : -1`. Or, to be sneaky (and cryptic again), you can just multiply `originalSign` and `newSign`.

Comment: sadly you can not just multiply, e.g. originalSign is negative, and newSign is negative, too, you must not multiply it or you get a positive result. It would be less cryptic, yes :) you can not use `Math.Sign()` in this particular expression, because it would return an `int` instead of a `bool`. Cory Nelson gave a good answer using `Math.Sign()`, I wanted to stay in the original logic and just shorten it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonably short and easy to understand, plus the implementation for floating-point types would be identical:

```
int myValue = -4;
int newValue = some_operation(myValue);

if ( (myValue < 0) ^ (newValue < 0) )
{
    newValue = -newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it is the most elegant way. But following code could address the co-ordinate manipulation. (y/absY) gives us the sign. absY is a magnitude.

```
int absX = Math.Abs(x);
int absY = Math.Abs(y);

if(  absX >  absY)
   y = (y/absY)*absX;
else if(  absX <  absY)
   x = (x/absX)*absY;
```